# Deducing argument for a function that uses recurring template

Tags: c++, templates

i got the error from code below. What is wrong? Everything seems to be in place.

> error C2784: 'void Menu::AddLeaf(Command,const int)' : could not
>   deduce template argument for 'Command' from
>   'LauncherCommandChangeSimulation'

**Command.h**

```
template <class Receiver>
class Command
{
    virtual void Execute() = 0;
    ...
};
```

**LauncherCommand.h**

```
#include "Menu/Command.h"
#include "Internal/Launcher.h"
class LauncherCommand : public Command<Launcher>
{ ... };

class LauncherCommandChangeSimulation : public LauncherCommand
{ ... };
```

**Menu.h**

```
template <class T>
class Command;

class Menu
{
public:
    template <class T>
    void AddLeaf(Command<T> command, const int parentId);
};
```

**Game.cpp**

```
#include "Internal/Launcher.h"
#include "Menu/Menu.h"
#include "Menu/LauncherCommand.h"

LauncherCommandChangeSimulation command(...);

menu.AddLeaf(command, ...); // Error here
```

---

If i change call to AddLeaf on

```
menu.AddLeaf<Launcher>(command, simsNodeId);
```

then i get next error

> error C2770: invalid explicit template argument(s) for 'void
>   Menu::AddLeaf(Command,const int)'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're trying to pass a derived-class object to a function that takes the `Command` base class by value. That will try to *slice* the object, copying the base sub-object and discarding everything that makes it a `LauncherCommand` and a `LauncherCommandChangeSimulation`. Even if that worked, it would not be what you want; and in this case it won't work, since the base class is abstract and so can't be instantiated as a complete object.

You'll need some kind of indirection in order to store polymorphic objects in the menu. It looks like you'll need a further, non-template, base class, and `AddLeaf` will need to take and store a (preferably smart) pointer to that.

Answer (score 2):

It works if the `command` parameter is taken by reference.

[LIVE DEMO](http://ideone.com/RGev9Y)

This is because of §14.8.2.1(4):

> In general, the deduction process attempts to find template argument values that will make the deduced `A` identical to `A` (after the type `A` is transformed as described above). However, there are three cases that allow a difference:
>
> - ...
> - ...
> - If `P` is a class and `P` has the form *simple-template-id*, then the transformed `A` can be a derived class of the deduced `A`. Likewise, if `P` is a pointer to a class of the form *simple-template-id*, the transformed `A` can be a pointer to a derived class pointed to by the deduced `A`.

But then you would need to deal with the object's lifetime management, so Mike is correct that you'll be wanting a smart pointer instead.